# How can I reverse this alphabet id getting system to go the other way around?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this function makes it possible to get an alphabet character or multiple depending on what number you send in. I want to reverse this function so that when I send in the character, I receive a number. I have been able to achieve this with single letters.

I have already created an alphabetic id system by first generating a number then converting it into a letter in the alphabet using this id as the index. But what I want to do is after 26 characters have been used i would like for it to continue with AA, AB, AC and so on.

EDIT: I want to clarify that my thought was that the converter should extend beyond 
A-series. So after AZ it goes to BA BB.. BZ, CA CB CC and so on.
Also what i want get return is a number and not the letter. The original function gives me the letters, now I need to reverse it to get back the number i sent in the previous function

```
function convertNumberToId (number) {
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');

    if (number < alphabet.length) {
      return alphabet[number];
    } else {
      return (
        convertNumberToId(Math.floor(number / alphabet.length) - 1)
        +
        convertNumberToId(number % alphabet.length)
      );
    }
}
```

In the if statement you get a letter back if the number does not exceed the length of the array but once it does you'll get AA, AB, AC and so on. Now I want to reverse this.

This is what I have achieved so far:

```
function convertIdToNumber(id){
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    if($.inArray(id , alphabet) !== -1){
        return alphabet.indexOf(id);
    }
    else{

    }

}
```

Comment: so you want to return a character based on its index in the alphabet?

Comment: @mding5692 I think he is already doing that. He wants it to return AA if you input, say, 27, AB if you input 28. At least that is how I understood it

Comment: @Ronnie Yes that's exactly correct

Comment: I feel like the route is take the difference of 26 characters and then do another index of, so like `28 % 26` gives you a remainder of 2 which would be B. Obviously not thinking in zero based right now but you get the idea

Comment: You mean like the original function converting number into alphabetic letters?

Comment: You might consider using `toString(26)` and `map` to get the right character

Comment: @CertainPerformance You're a genius! I think i've got an idea. I'll update you guys on my progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function convertIdToNumber(id){
    const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    if ($.inArray(id , alphabet) !== -1){
        // Can remove the add one here if you want 'a' = 0 
        return alphabet.indexOf(id) + 1; 
    } else {      
        return (Math.pow(26, id.length - 1) * (alphabet.indexOf(id.charAt(0)) + 1)) +  convertIdToNumber(id.slice(1));
    }
}
console.log(convertIdToNumber("aa")); // 27
console.log(convertIdToNumber("ab")); // 28
console.log(convertIdToNumber("ac")); // 29
console.log(convertIdToNumber("zz")); // 702
console.log(convertIdToNumber("abc")); // 731
```

JQuery live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/chkt65n7/5/

I used your original function but I assumed "a" in this case was 1 as you mentioned "aa" was 27 but if that part is different then you can minus the one from the ending recursive case if you want.

**Revised to handle more than 2 characters in a string**

Answer (score 4):

**REVISED (Start at 0 Index)**

Now we calculate value from right to left. As you move to the left, the value of the character is multiplied by the length of the alphabet raised to the number of digits you've moved left. Handle offset of 1.

```js
function convertNumberToId (number) {
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');

    if (number < alphabet.length) {
      return alphabet[number];
    } else {
      return (
        convertNumberToId(Math.floor(number / alphabet.length) - 1)
        +
        convertNumberToId(number % alphabet.length)
      );
    }
}

function convertIdToNumber(id){
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    if(id.length == 1){
        return alphabet.indexOf(id) >= 0 ? alphabet.indexOf(id) : -1;
    }
    else if (id.length > 0){
        let t = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
          t += (1 + convertIdToNumber(id.charAt(id.length - 1 - i))) * Math.pow(alphabet.length, i);
        }
        t--;
        return t;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

}

console.log(convertIdToNumber('b'));
console.log(convertNumberToId(1));
console.log(convertIdToNumber('abc'));
console.log(convertNumberToId(730));
```

---

Find the value of each character in the id, add the length of the alphabet for each additional character, and handle the offset of 1 when you have multiple characters.

**Start at index 0**

```js
function convertIdToNumber(id){
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    if(id.length == 1){
        return alphabet.indexOf(id);
    }
    else if (id.length > 0) {
        return convertIdToNumber(id.split('')[0]) 
            + alphabet.length 
            + convertIdToNumber(id.slice(1))
            + 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

console.log(convertIdToNumber('ac'));
```

**Start at index 1**

```js
function convertIdToNumber(id){
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    if(id.length == 1){
        return alphabet.indexOf(id) >= 0 ? alphabet.indexOf(id) + 1 : -1;
    }
    else if (id.length > 0) {
        return convertIdToNumber(id.split('')[0]) 
            + alphabet.length 
            + convertIdToNumber(id.slice(1))
            - 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

console.log(convertIdToNumber('ac'));
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but does not allow for continuation beyond the A-series. What I'm thinking is continuing after AZ toward BA BB BC and so on

Comment: @IvanSedelkin I believe the update allows for continuation beyond the A-Series and  any number of characters in the id.

Comment: There is an issue with the numbers below 26. Ex `convertNumberToId('5') !== convertIdToNumber(convertNumberToId('5'))`. Made a small test to illustrate the issue https://jsbin.com/qehopozequ/edit?js,console

Comment: @Pablo You're right! I had assumed 'a' was 1, revised to fix this issue